# Set timeout with HttpClientHandler

Tags: c#, anglesharp

I am trying to set the timeout value of anglesharp.io using HttpClientHandler.

This issue suggests it is possible: https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/issues/266

I am getting page like this:

```
        NetworkCredential proxyCreds = new NetworkCredential(proxy.User, proxy.Pass);

        WebProxy wProxy = new WebProxy(proxy.Ip + ":" + proxy.Port, false)
        {
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = proxyCreds,
        };

        HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            Proxy = wProxy,
            PreAuthenticate = true,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false
        };

        var config = Configuration.Default.WithRequesters(httpClientHandler);

        var document = await BrowsingContext.New(config).OpenAsync(address);
```

I cannot see any properties available to set the timeout.  How do I set the timeout?

Comment: You can't set timeout on `HttpClientHandler`. You need to pass `HttpClientHandler` to `HttpClient`. Check this- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/henrikn/2012/08/07/httpclient-httpclienthandler-and-webrequesthandler-explained/

Comment: Anglesharp is abstracting this process.  Page I linked to says I need to make IRequester but I am not sure what that is.  I have made workaround using httpclient directly but curious how to make it work in anglesharp.

Comment: Well in that case you might have to go through the API/documentation of anglesharp

Comment: The issue I linked in question is only reference, i have read all documents

Comment: I think you should go ahead with `HttpClient` in case there are no such way using anglesharp. It might give more control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments above are right. AngleSharp is abstracting requesters away - to allow multiple types of requesters and provide flexibility if needed. The essential interface is `IRequester` (note: there is no HTTP on purpose - in AngleSharp.Io we also find, e.g., a `FileRequester` that accesses the local file system for file:// URIs).

We could now either implement our own requester or just use the `HttpClientRequester` from AngleSharp.Io with the constructor overload accepting an `HttpClient` instance.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.Timeout = MyCustomTimeout; //Whatever value you want it to be
var requester = new HttpClientRequester(client);
```

Now the question is how can you use this requester? We just create a configuration (as usual) and use the default loader extension method (as usual), however, this time with our custom requester.

For pre 0.10 this looks as follows:

```
 // Assumes we do not want to provide custom options for the loaders
 var requesters = new [] { requester };
 var configuration = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader(requesters: requesters);
```

For 0.10 and later this looks a bit different:

```
 var configuration = Configuration.Default.WithRequester(requester).WithDefaultLoader();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much Florian!  I knew there must be a way but I couldn't figure it out so I went with passing string from HttpClient.  I will try this way in future.

Comment: For those like me that can use the requester from Florian in 'var configuration = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader(requesters: requesters);' use instead of requesters --> new [] { requester }. Maybe obvious for many but wasn't for me. In a way it's Florian that gave me the answer here : https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/issues/367

Comment: Thanks @samuelguedon - I've added the declaration of requesters to my answer!

Comment: @FlorianRapp, in AngleSharp 0.14.0-alpha-787 I can't see a `WithDefaultLoader` overload as the one in the reply. Maybe it's defined in other assemblies than **AngleSharp.dll** and **AngleSharp.Io.dll**? I think that `WithDefaultLoader().WithRequester(requester)` should properly configure a custom requester.

Comment: The `WithDefaultLoader` overload taking the requesters is gone since 0.10 I think. I've updated the solution! Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's needed to have different timeouts on the level of `HttpClient` and `HttpClientHandler`, for example kind of retry logic, seamless for `HttpClient` - wait for 5 minutes, but retry every minute. In this case one can use a delegating handler like following:

```
public class RetryHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly TimeSpan timeout;

    public RetryHandler(TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        this.timeout = timeout;
    }

    private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Delay(
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await Task.Delay(timeout, cancellationToken);

        return null;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        for (; ; )
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            var delayTask = Delay(cancellationToken);
            var firstCompleted = await Task.WhenAny(
                base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken), delayTask);

            if (firstCompleted != delayTask)
                return await firstCompleted;
        }
    }
}
```

Use case:

```
var client = new HttpClient(
new RetryHandler(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)))
{
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
};

client.PostAsync(...);
```